# KnockoutJS with MVC, Model and functions

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am working on a project which includes MVC and KnockoutJS. As this is the first time i'm working with KnockoutJS i'm running into a lot of issues.
I want to put my MVC Viewmodel on the webpage in a tabbed interface. Then from that interface i want to call functions depending on which button i press.

Currently i am getting the model to load and show itself fine, but i cannot call any functions i am trying to create.
Also i have no clue that the way i am creating this at the moment is the correct one.

I have the following model:

```
    public partial class SSoSearchModel
{
    public string SearchParameter { get; set; }
    public string SearchValue { get; set; }
    public string SearchLabel { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<SsoRecordResultViewModel> searchResults { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> ParameterList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> LabelList { get; set; }
}
```

The SearchResults look like this

```
    public partial class SsoRecordResultViewModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email_address"), DefaultValue(PropertyName = "email_addresses")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "phone_number"), DefaultValue(PropertyName = "phone_numbers")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Klantnummer"), CustomAttribute(PropertyName = "Klantnummer")]
    public string Klantnummer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "verzekerdenummer"), CustomAttribute(PropertyName = "Verzekerdennummer")]
    public string Verzekerdenummer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "person_id")]
    public string SSOID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "initials")]
    public string Initialen { get; set; }
}
```

And this is all loaded in the Index function of the controller with dummy data

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {

        List<SsoRecordResultViewModel> temp = new List<SsoRecordResultViewModel>();
        temp.Add(new SsoRecordResultViewModel { SSOID = "ea373d27-142d-48f6-86c9-dcdb15e316d2", EmailAddress = "A", FirstName = "a", Klantnummer = "1", Verzekerdenummer = "1", PhoneNumber = "1", Initialen = "A", LastName = "a" });
        temp.Add(new SsoRecordResultViewModel { SSOID = "2d613aba-3f89-43b0-919a-1aa615086ff3", EmailAddress = "b", FirstName = "b", Klantnummer = "2", Verzekerdenummer = "2", PhoneNumber = "2", Initialen = "b", LastName = "b" });
        temp.Add(new SsoRecordResultViewModel { SSOID = "c142f22e-7664-4a9c-9303-293b48acbf65", EmailAddress = "c", FirstName = "c", Klantnummer = "3", Verzekerdenummer = "3", PhoneNumber = "3", Initialen = "c", LastName = "c" });

        SSoSearchModel model = new SSoSearchModel();
        model.searchResults = temp.AsQueryable(); //Enumerable.Empty<SsoRecordResultViewModel>().AsQueryable();

        //zoekopties
        model.ParameterList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        model.ParameterList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Zoek op Klantnummer", Value = "Klantnummer" });
        model.ParameterList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Zoek op Verzekerdenummer", Value = "Verzekerdenummer" });
        model.ParameterList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Zoek op E-mail adres", Value = "Email" });
        model.ParameterList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Zoek op SSO ID", Value = "SSOID" });
        model.ParameterList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Zoek op Telefoonnummer", Value = "Telefoonnummer" });

        //Labels
        model.LabelList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        model.LabelList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Rel1", Value = "Rel1" });
        model.LabelList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Rel2", Value = "Rel2" });

        return View(model);
    }
```

Now on the Index.cshtml i offcourse have my markup which shows the data great at the moment, but the KnockoutJS is the issue.

The javascript looks the following:

```
    <script>

    function ViewModel() { 
        var self = this;
        self.Search = ko.observableArray(searchResults);

        self.save = function(ssoid){
            //ajax hier
        };
    };

    var rawData = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
    var Data = ko.mapping.fromJS(rawData,ViewModel);

    ko.applyBindings(Data);


</script>
```

This currently shows me the data, but i do not know how i can call the save function. I have this but this does not work:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Bewaren" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Bewaar de gegevens" data-bind="click: function() { $data.save(SSOID()); }"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

Also when i swap the values in ko.mapping.fromJS(rawData,ViewModel); the data does not get shown anymore.
Anyone here who can help me with this as it is driving me crazy.

Comment: As far as I know just calling `data-bind="click: save()"` should work.

Comment: I suggest making the code a more *minimal* repro. Very likely you'll find the root cause yourself, if not that it'll make it a lot more pleasant and easy for us to help you. (E.g. remove the bootstrap bits, restrict the repro to a front-end or a back-end issue / remove the back-end bits, remove as many properties as will still allow for a repro, etc). See "[mcve]" for guidance.

Comment: I haven't looked at all your code (As Jeroen pointed out, there's a bit too much of it), but one thing caught my attention: you're passing your `ViewModel` constructor to `ko.mapping.fromJS` rather than a `ViewModel` instance. Also, I don't see `searchResults` defined anywhere. I'd suggest calling `ko.mapping.fromJS` _inside_ `ViewModel` and passing `rawData` as a parameter.